# How to feed in an answer to input in script in Python

Tags: python

```
def foo():
    return raw_input("answer this question: ")


# some code here then
foo()
# some more code here
```

`foo` is 3rd party function call and it somehow triggers an input.

How can we feed an answer in there if we know the answer in advance?
No Popen; i am not even running a script file. One way I can think of is using thread?

Comment: What do you mean by "feed an answer in there"?  Can you set a default?  command line options?

Comment: Like I said, this is a third party function. Feed as in answer the input, but do this in the same code as I am calling this third party. If you call ``foo`` and ``foo`` somehow contains ``raw_input``, how would you answer the input in code, instead of interactive?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A little unorthodox, but you can monkey-patch `sys.stdin`:

```
# We're going to monkey-patch stdin
import sys
from cStringIO import StringIO
old = sys.stdin
sys.stdin = StringIO('hello')

# Now read from stdin
result = raw_input('foo')

# And replace the regular stdin
sys.stdin = old
```

This will work as if you typed 'hello' as the input for `raw_input`. Of course, rather than calling `raw_input` yourself, you'd be calling your `foo` function. I think if I were going to do this more than once, I'd use a context manager to be certain I undo the monkey patch:

```
import sys
from cStringIO import StringIO

class PatchStdin(object):
    def __init__(self, value):
        self._value = value
        self._stdin = sys.stdin
    def __enter__(self):
        # Monkey-patch stdin
        sys.stdin = StringIO(self._value)
        return self
    def __exit__(self, typ, val, traceback):
        # Undo the monkey-patch
        sys.stdin = self._stdin


# Usage
with PatchStdin('Dan'):
    name = raw_input('What is your name? ')
    print 'Hello, %s' % name
```

Comment: oh I think I should have not do ``.write``. That was the trick. This is definitely inline with something I was thinking. Thanks.

Comment: I don't think redirecting `stdin` would be considered monkey-patching.

Comment: That's fair, though in my mind, swapping out members of a module like `sys` is in the same vein. Still, risky business that should be approached with caution.